# How to avoid getChildView in ExpandableListView getting called when clicking on done in keypad

Tags: java, android, expandablelistadapter

I have Edittext in one of the child in ExpandableListView. In EditText when clicking on done button in keypad, getChildView is getting called automatically.How to avoid that. Also I want to know why getChildView is getting called unnecessarily.Anybody help me to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that the event: KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER is sent to your ExpandableListView, in that case, calling getChildView is pretty normal.

If you want to avoid that just overwrite the listener or make ExpandableListView lose focus.

Comment: is that possible to avoid going to getchildview?

Comment: I have tried this ```parent.clearChildFocus(view);``` after this, Text in EditText field is not cleared when clicking on done button. But when I try to hide keyboard, again text is cleared..